# Get value from json object with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new at working with JSON objects and I have been trying to find an answer on here but the common method I have seen being used is not working for me.

I am trying to get the value 21 from the JSON object I can inspect in my javascript console.

```
^Object { number: Object }
    ^number: Object
        min: 21
    >_proto_: Object
```

The name of the JSON object is `answer` so I tried to use `JSON.parse`

```
obj = JSON.parse(answer);
console.log(answer.min);
```

Or this

```
obj = JSON.parse(answer);
console.log(answer.number.min);
```

I know I'm missing something simple but I'm a visual learner and the docs don't do much for me.

Comment: try obj['min'] or obj.min

Comment: What is the console saying? Is there any error? JSON.parse() will turn a string in JSON format into a Javascript object. JSON.stringify() does the opposite.

Comment: Based on all of your comments on other answers, your question does not have enough details of the issue.  They've answered the question based on what you've given us, but it sounds like that's still now working.  Post a fiddle demonstrating the error.  If `console.log(answer)` shows what you've pasted there, then `answer.number.min === 21` -- see [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/vitulazuga/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: What is a JSON object?  Is that sort of like a JavaScript object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the comment fields from another post, and if answer really is just an object, then the following should work.

`obj = answer.number.min`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need `obj.number.min`, provided `answer` is a string.

Comment: I just tried it and still nothing gets logged to the console.

Comment: Then why are you parsing it?

Comment: I've been looking to it for the past hour so I thought I'd head over here and ask. I don't really know how to get my value. I just need that number 21 to be saved in a variable.

Comment: we need more context. `JSON.parse` might be throwing